# How to get a value passed to a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

i read Angularjs documentation .thereare examples for defining directives without passing a value.for example:

```
angular.module('docsTemplateUrlDirective', [])
.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.customer = {
    name: 'Naomi',
    address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
  };
}])
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'my-customer.html'
  };
});
```

and HTML is

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
  <div my-customer></div>
</div>
```

but i want to create a directive like ng-model in which an attribute get passed.for example

```
 <div ng-controller="Controller">
      <div my-customer="Hello"></div>
    </div>
```

i want to retrieve this hello in my directive definition link function.How to achieve that ??

Answer (score 1):

You can pass as many as attributes and can access them directly using third argument in link function. Here you go:

```
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'my-customer.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
       console.log('Attribute:', attr.myCustomer, attr.otherData);
    }
  };
});

<div my-customer="hello" other-data="foo"></div>
```

Comment: thanks pal.will accept ur answer in 8 minutes.restricted by stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Just scroll a lil more in docs (**[Angular Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)**) where you got above code, you will get how to get your answer `attr` of directive

```
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
return {
templateUrl: function(elem, attr){
  ...
  //attr will be having the value 
  return attr;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use isolated scope, then you can do this:

```
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      myCustomer : '=' //If expected value is an object use '='. If it is just text, use '@'
    }
    templateUrl: 'my-customer.html',
    link: function(scope, ele, attr){
       console.log(scope.myCustomer);
    }
  };
});
```

If you don't want to use isolated scope, then

```
.directive('myCustomer', function($parse) {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'my-customer.html',
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, ele, attr){
       // if expected value is object
      var hello = $parse(attr.myCustomer)(scope);

       // if expected value is just text
      var hello = attr.myCustomer;

    }
  };
});
```